# How to convert folder path to Content Uri?

Tags: android, file, uri, android-contentprovider, storage-access-framework

I have a File variable, which is actually a Folder path. I want to get its Uri.
If I use

```
Uri.fromFile(myFile);
```

I get something like "file:///mnt/sdcard".
What I'd like to get is content scheme Uri, like "content://com.externalstorage/" so that I can use it with DocumentFile.

Comment: Do you want to get URI for media file?

Comment: No. I want to get content Uri for FOLDER / DIRECTORY. I can easily get it through StorageAccessFramework. But it's invalid when getting folder path like "/mnt/sdcard/".

Comment: If you do not write a content provider for that path yourself then there will be none.

Comment: What do you mean that you can easily get it through SAF? /mnt/sdcard will be just SAF's primary tree.

Comment: Why do you want to use DocumentFile where that is so terrible slow and inefficient compared to 'what we used to do'?

Comment: @greenapps I'm trying to figure out how this "post KITKAT" Storage Access Framework works. The thing is, my app needs to access external storage media, like USB. As I understood, From Kitkat and above, external storage is read-only and the path is randomly generated ID like "/mnt/media_rw/3BG2-G9TZ". It is only accessible through SAF. Am I wrong?

Comment: External storage is still read/write. But removable strage like micro sd card and usb flash are read only with conventional access. Only app specific directories are writable too. Use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE and ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to access SAF.

Answer (score 0):

1.You have to access Storage Access Framework with this code

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 99);
```

2.After that you will get access Storage Access Framework, you need to choose the file as you want. Then it will give you an uri of that file onActivityResult.

```
    if (requestCode == 99 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    Uri uri = null;
    if (resultData != null) {
        uri = resultData.getData();
    }
}
```

3. Finally you got the uri file.

Comment: That gives me file Uri. I need to get folder uri and use it.